# Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I can't locate this error...:/

I'm working with nibs, and I tried to read some of the answers to this similar errors and found not link it to hide, can someone please help?

Let me know if you want me to provide more info , tnx

this is my HomeViewController nib file: (it's my root view controller where I get the warning in the log):

[image]

I think its got something to do with the fact that I deleted the default classes apple giving you when creating a single view application. But maybe I didn't know I need to delete it somewhere else too..?

Comment: That's not enough information.

Comment: your xib couldnot able to find viewcontroller please specify your viewcontroller in xib

Comment: Please provide more information in your question. What is your exact requirement? What error are you facing?

Comment: Do you have a `HomeViewController.h` & `HomeViewController.m` or `HomeViewController.swift` file that has a class `HomeViewController` which should subclass `UIViewController`

Comment: yes I do have HomeViewController.h and.m @sbarow

Answer (score 3):

You might have set the **custom class** of your nib to a class that **does not exist**.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: check out the screen shot of my root view controller where i get the error

Comment: i have the HomeViewController.h and.m, so I don't know where is this ViewController coming from

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced this kind of issue. Check in .h file HomeViewController might not be inheriting the UIViewController class.
In .h file you should have something like this

Interface HomeViewController: UIViewController
{

}

Answer (score 0):

If your are using pods make sure you are linking against the corresponding library.